# How to run sails 1.0 in console mode when using typescript

Tags: sails.js, command-line-interface

Sails 1.0-beta now [supports TypeScript](http://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-type-script).

To do so, you need to add something in your *app.js* file and run your app using `node app.js` instead of the usual `sails lift` or `sails console`.
While this works great to replace `sails lift`, I find myself missing the console mode, really handy to run quick tests.

I tried running `node app.js console` and `node app.js --console` but it just lifts the app in regular mode.
I suspect I need to change something in my app.js but I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Does anyone knows how to run sails-1.0-beta with typescript compatibility and in console mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hackish way

1. Find your sails (global) installation. Possible locations:

   - `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`
   - `~/.nvm/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/node_modules`
2. Add a line in `bin/sails.js` in this location (same line as your `app.js`)

   - `require('typescript-require');`
   - OR `require('ts-node/register');`

This will affect all sails project which use this global sails installation

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm (I obviously had to run `npm install typescript ts-node/register` in _/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails_). 
I'm not accepting your answer straight away as I hope to get something more sustainable but this is definitely a good fit for my use case.

Comment: A slightly better way is to make this change in the local sails module (_<app_dir>/node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js_). That way you can run your app in console mode using `./node_modules/.bin/sails console` and leave untouched your global sails install.